# No data received in Mongodb Atlas collection, even though connection is established with app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using node.js and heroku to deploy my app online, with mongodb atlas as my database, but for some reason, no data is being collected in the collections section of the database. I have checked the logs, and there is no connection error mentioned.

[As you can see, the logs shows "database opened".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIMpQ.jpg)

Here is the code for my app.js file:

```
// --- LOADING MODULES
var express = require('express'),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
body_parser = require('body-parser');

// --- INSTANTIATE THE APP
var app = express();

// --- MONGOOSE SETUP
mongoose.connect(process.env.CONNECTION || 'mongodb://localhost/sopp-survey'); 
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error'));
db.once('open', function callback() {
    console.log('database opened');
});

var emptySchema = new mongoose.Schema({}, { strict: false });
var Entry = mongoose.model('Entry', emptySchema);


// --- STATIC MIDDLEWARE 
app.use('/jspsych-6.0.5', express.static(__dirname + "/jspsych-6.0.5"));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + "/css"));
app.use('/img', express.static(__dirname + "/img"));

// --- BODY PARSING MIDDLEWARE
app.use(body_parser.json()); // to support JSON-encoded bodies

// --- VIEW LOCATION, SET UP SERVING STATIC HTML
app.set('views', __dirname + '/');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

// --- ROUTING
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.render('index.html');
});

app.get('/experiment', function(request, response) {
    response.render('experiment_pilot.html');
});

app.post('/experiment-data', function(request, response){
    Entry.create({
        "data":request.body
    });    
    response.end();
})
// --- START THE SERVER 
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT, function(){
    console.log("Listening on port %d", server.address().port);
});
```

I have specified the env variable CONNECTION using the command:

```
heroku config:set CONNECTION=mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@CLUSTER_URL/MY_DB_NAME?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "jspsych_survey",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "ejs": "^3.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.6",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.x"
  }
}
```

On running the app locally, everything seems to work fine, even the data gets sent to the local database, which I access using the Mongo shell.

Is there something wrong with the code? Can anyone suggest what I can do to resolve this issue? 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi From the warning messeges in logs in seems that yo are using some deprecated method to connect your application.

So, use the new method to connect to your application.